# Visual Studio Code: .git folder/file hidden

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying Visual Studio Code at this moment. Everything about Visual Studio Code look really cool to me except one thing: **.git folder/file is hidden in Visual Studio Code.**

I often change Git setting by modifying the `.git` configuration file. It is really annoying for me not able to see `.git` files.

Is there a way to reveal `.git` files in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea

Comment: I often change git settings too. But I don't care if the .git folder is visible or hidden and where inside it are the settings stored. And you know why? Because is none of my business to know. [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) knows and that's enough for me. Nevertheless, you posted a good question :-)

Comment: @HongOoi @axiac That's not totally true. Sometimes you might want to edit the **hooks** which reside in the `.git/hooks` folder.

Comment: and sometimes you might want to delete the folder without the commandline

Answer (score 376, accepted):

By default Visual Studio Code excludes files in a folder using the following settings:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
}
```

You can change your user settings or workspace settings to show the .git folder by adding these lines:

```
"files.exclude": {
     "**/.git": false
}
```

This setting can also be found in `Text Editor` -> `Files` -> `Exclude` if you are using the settings GUI.

---

To open the settings JSON for editing, do the following:

1. Open the command pallete:

   Windows: `ctrl+shift+p`

   or

   Mac: `⌘ + Shift + P`
2. In the command prompt that should open, type `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.

   This should open the settings JSON file for you.

   *Note: You will notice similar commands appear if you prefer to choose settings more specific to your user or workspace.*
3. Find `files.exclude` and you should see the relevant section to edit.

Comment: In case anyone else trips up over this - you *have* to set the exclusion explicitly to false - removing the `"**/.git": true` setting is not enough, as it defaults to true if missing.

Comment: @NishantSingh where can I find that setting?

Comment: @IshanPatel Just press ⌘, and paste the settings there.

Comment: For those wondering/new to VS Code, if you open the Command Palette (on Mac, its ⌘ + Shift + P) and then type "Settings", the first search result should be "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" which will open `settings.json` in VSCode for you to edit. Save any changes and VS Code should pick them up immediately. Edit: Vikash's answer below is also excellent, be sure to upvote it as well!

Comment: If you define `"files.exclude"` in your User settings, and than also again in your Workspace settings, does the Workspace setting object overwrite the *entire* User setting object, or only on a per-property basis? For example: User setting: `"files.exclude": {"**/.git": false, "**/.svn": false}`; Workspace setting: `"files.exclude": {"**/.git": true}`. What will be the effective value of `"**/.svn"` in the Workspace? Will it be `false` as specified in the User or `true` as specified by default?

Comment: Apr 2021 update: Seems like VSCode now shows up `Files: Exclude` as a list, and `**/.git` has to be removed from it. `Files: Exclude` property is accessible via Settings.

Comment: Works when I add it to my user settings, but when added to the workspace settings it tells me "Unsupported Property". Does this setting work per workspace?

Answer (score 50):

The below steps can be followed to override the existing user setting:

1. Menu *Code* → *Preference* → *Setting*
2. Search for `files.exclude`
3. Mouse over `files.exclude` property, click on the edit icon and then opt for the copy to settings.
4. The above steps will add all the properties, but keep only those which need to be overridden. For this case: it should be, "files.exclude": { "**/.git": false }
5. Close the user setting. the `.git` folder will automatically appear in the respective repository.

Comment: I found this answer to be the easiest to follow 

Comment: In newer VS Code versions you should just remove `**/.git` from said settings. No need to set anything to `false`.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to configure vscode to show .git directory, you need to settings in vscode by (cmd + ,) or (ctrl + ,). If you do it you will see a search bar, type "Files: Exclude" , when you see the top result just hover over the .git row and you will see a close icon or a delete icon. Click on that. After you click on that done! Now you will be able to see the .git directory in the vscode explorer.

Answer (score 9):

The settings for Visual Studio Code can be found:

- On a Windows or Linux computer, click menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*
- On a Mac, click menu *Code* → *Preferences* → *Settings*

There are both users settings (for everyone) and workspace settings for individual projects.

More instructions can be found at:
*[User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)*

Answer (score 8):

Go to vscode and find the setting.json file. For

Windows: ctr+p and find >setting.json file or
mac: command+p and find >setting.json file in the search bar

add

```
"files.exclude": {
     "**/.git": false
}
```

This will work

Comment: This is basically the same as the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828248/10095231), except that it mentions "ctrl+p". Instead of that, I'd suggest to add that information as an edit to or as a comment under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

**It's probably best to leave this hidden**

If you are using the sidebar to navigate and edit files, it would leave an opportunity to accidentally drop a file or folder in it, or accidentally move it to a different location.  A better solution would be to open a terminal session in Visual Studio Code and then do `code .git`.  That will open the folder in another Visual Studio Code instance and from there you can edit it.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who only wants to view very specific things in the `.git` folder, here's one way to do that (add to your vscode settings JSON):

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/.git": false,
  "**/.git/{branches,info,hooks,logs,objects,*refs,COMM*,desc*,*HEAD,index,}": true,
},
```

The above will only show the `config` file. You can modify this list to your liking. For example, by removing `hooks` from the list, vscode will show the `hooks` folder as well as the config file:

```
"**/.git/{branches,info,logs,objects,*refs,COMM*,desc*,*HEAD,index,}": true,
```

Maybe you have more stuff in you `.git` directory, I don't know everything git can possibly put in there. Just add it to the list if you don't want to see it.

Note that this will protect you from acidentally deleting important, specific things in the `.git` directory. However, you are still running the risk of acidentally deleting the entire `.git` directory. Which, needless to say, would be extremely bad in many situations.

I found another, slightly less convenient way: You can "Add Folder to Workspace..." and choose the `.git/hooks` directory. You might have to enable showing hidden files in your file explorer first. This doesn't work for files, like the config file, as far as I'm aware. And you'd have to do it for each one of your workspaces.

Stay safe! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should also be aware of the `search.useIgnoreFiles` setting, which will ignore files and folders that are ignored using `.gitignore` and `.ignore` files.

Comment: I knew I was on the wrong SO post for my problem, but I was counting on a good soul to give a direction on how to fix my search patterns. So thanks for that @Arik !!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I did not find this EXCLUDE setting in my settings.json file.

So what I did instead is, since I know the file path already, I used my terminal to access the .git/hooks directory.

On same terminal I used the command below

```
>> code .
```

Comment: The better solution would be to do `code .git/hooks` or `code .git/hooks/<hook filename>` directly. I get what you tried to do here, but just in case, I'm commenting on why you can't see the setting: not all settings are shown on the settings.json file. Only modified settings get added to that file, any setting that just use the defaults would not be shown there. You can use the settings UI to find and edit `files.exclude` and that would put the setting in settings.json file.

Comment: Although, if you just need to edit some file inside .git folder, I think opening that folder or file directly is much better, than editing files.exclude to permanently showing it every time.

Answer (score -2):

You can access this setting in the settings option.

Then we need to copy this particular settings section to the right side and make the changes.

Comment: Can you add exactly how to do it (***without*** "Update:", "Edit:", etc.)?