# Git file doesn't show up after being created in the windows powershell

Tags: github, git-init

I created a git folder in the windows power shell using the code:  git init,
but I can't see the folder where I created it.
If git folders are hidden then how can I access them and make them visible because I want them to show up in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make hidden folder visible.

### In windows:

1. Open File Explorer from the taskbar.
2. Select View > Options > Change folder and search options.
3. Select the View tab and, in Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives and OK.

[View hidden files and folders Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10)

### In Visual Studio Code.

1. Menu Code → Preference → Setting
2. Search for files.exclude
3. Mouse over files.exclude property, click on the edit icon and then opt for the copy to settings.
4. The above steps will add all the properties, but keep only those which need to be overridden. For this case: it should be, `"files.exclude": { "**/.git": false }`
5. Close the user
   setting. the .git folder will automatically appear in the respective
   repository.

[Visual Studio Code: .git folder/file hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818354/visual-studio-code-git-folder-file-hidden)